# Can't get parent position from convert view

Tags: java, android, adapter, convertview

I have a listView that currently displays the names of images along with a thumb of the image beside it.  I highlight the selected textBox green onClick, but while scrolling through the list other items are highlighted as well.

**ADAPTER:**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private ArrayList<String> data;
   private Boolean[] isSelected;
   private Activity activity;
   private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
   public ImageLoader imageLoader;
   View vi;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> c){
    activity = a;
    data = c;       
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    isSelected = new Boolean[data.size()];
    System.out.println("data size :  " + data.size());
    for(int i =0; i < isSelected.length; i++)isSelected[i] = false;
}
public int getCount(){
    return data.size();
}
public Object getItem(int position){
    return data.get(position);  
}

public long getItemId(int position){        
    return position;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    vi=convertView;
    if(convertView == null) // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.each, null);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

        /////////////////!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! HERE
        if(isSelected[position])text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        text.setText("image: "+ data.get(position).substring(data.get(position).lastIndexOf("/")+1, data.get(position).indexOf(".jpg")));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(position), image);

        return vi;
    }
public void setMy_ItemSelected(int position, Boolean tf){/////each convertview resets this value?
    System.out.println("selected position size of array: " + Integer.toString(isSelected.length));
    System.out.println("selected position: " + position);

    if(tf){ isSelected[position] = true;}
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    System.out.println("selected position true/false: " + isSelected);
}
```

}

**CLICK LISTENER:**

```
    private class dataExport implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        adapter.setMy_ItemSelected(position, true);

        /*FileDialog popWindow = new FileDialog();              //USB pop window for folder selection
        popWindow.open_PathSelector(MainActivity.this);
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two item view types: one for the selected item and one for all the unselected ones. The adapter will automatically take care of only passing the correct type into your `getView` method.

At the moment, your adapter knows of only one type of view, so it will just pass any recycled view it has available into your `getView` method - some of which may still have the green highlight.

You need to implement [getItemViewType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) and [getViewTypeCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) in your adapter and it will work.

#### Edit

I'm bored right now so here's what it should be like: :D

```
protected static final int TYPE_NORMAL = 0;
protected static final int TYPE_SELECTED = 1;
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return isSelected[position] ? TYPE_SELECTED : TYPE_NORMAL;
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, and I'll appreciate the upvote. One thing I forgot (but you probably already did anyway), in the interest of clean modularized code, you should replace `if(isSelected[position])` with `if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_SELECTED)`.