# change color of item in listview (without click)

Tags: android, listview, background-color, listviewitem, setbackground

I've tried to change the background color of specific items in a `ListView`.

first, catch it from database:

```
   ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db.getAllApps());

    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewApps);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

then I will set all apps in different color, if they have the tag **activated**

```
// if app is activated in db --> set another colour in ListView
private void setAppCheck(ListView list) {

    List<String> apps = db.getAllApps();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
        if (db.appActivated(apps.get(i)).equals("activated")) {
            list.setBackgroundColor(0xffaaaaaa);  // it changes ALL items...

        } else {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

And there is Problem, with `list.setItemChecked(i, true)` I can change it with a specific position, but how do I change the Background color of the specific Item in the `ListView`?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Use `Custom Adapter` and change it in `getView` method.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do what you're trying to do is writing your own [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) supporting two view types: activated apps and deactivated apps. Then in your `getView` method, when you're inflating your views, you can set the background color accordingly.

Having two item types will make the Android framework automatically pass only convert views of the correct type to `getView`, so the only time you need to check for the type is during creation.

You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386334/cant-get-parent-position-from-convert-view/22386540#22386540) helpful.

### Adapter basics

In Android, `Adapter`s are used to translate your data (in your case from an SQLite database) into `View`s that can be displayed in listviews, spinners, etc. (`AdapterView` to be specific). One of the most commonly used ones is the `CursorAdapter` which has basic infrastructure necessary when the associated data is supposed to be read from a cursor.

You will mainly need three methods in your adapter:
 - `getViewTypeCount` which will tell the framework how many *types* of views your adapter knows. For you this will be two: activated and deactivated apps.

- `getItemViewType` which, when passed a specific position in the data (here: the cursor), is able to decide which of those types that position falls into. For this, you will likely be able to reuse your `db.appActivated` code, at least in large parts.
- `getView`, which, when passed a position, can turn the data associated with that position into a `View` for display. Let's look at that last part in more depth.

Android does some **very** nifty stuff to make sure your app is fast and slick and responsive. One of those things is, it will only keep enough views around for all positions in the list that are displayed. So, if you have a list that can display 10 items at a time, but your data holds a million records, it will still only keep 10 views around (well, actually, a few more from when stuff is scrolled off screen, but definitely *not* the one million it would require for every data record).

When the time comes to actually turn data into visible representations - `getView` - it will pass an old, previously visible but now off screen view (a recycled view) in as the `convertView` parameter for you to try adapting it to display the data that's been requeusted. This is because inflating new views is comparatively more expensive than just taking an existing one and changing its texts or images or whatever. The view types you have told it about will help it to only pass the type of convert view into `getView` that is appropriate for the position that's been requested.

This way, you need to only inflate a new view if the passed convert view is inappropriate somehow. And inappropriate, in this case, usually only means "if it is null". So, usually, what you end up with is something very close to this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = // inflate a new view
    }
    // bind the convert view to the data, i.e. set its text views, images, and - in your case - background color
}
```

### A video says more than a thousand words

You may want to watch [this Google I/O keynote](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) for a more comprehensive explanation of how it all ties together.

Comment: ok, I can't do it. I don't understand it :(
I read that [link](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-list-view-from-database-with-cursor-adapter/) and your hint, but I don't know how it works...

Comment: thank you, the video and explanation was great, but I think I'm a Noob here.
managed another solution with setItemChecked...

Comment: Ok. Usually you'll be better off with a less elegant solution you fully understand than with an elegant one you only half understand, so IMO you went the right way then. When you've stretched your legs some more on Android, you may want to come back and change it into your own adapter, though. Ultimately, once you've grasped the concept, they give you a lot of power over how your data is displayed while keeping that nicely separated from your activity code. :)